# Selenium loop page refreshed in python

Tags: python, loops, selenium, click, refresh

I have some questions related to doing the loop with Selenium in Python. In fact,  I want to iterate a list of links tracked by 'driver.find_elements_by_id' and click on them one by one, but the problem is such that each time I click on the link ('linklist' in the code), the page is refreshed so there is an error message indicating that 
'Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.'

I know that the reason is because the list of links disappeared after the click. But how can I generally in Selenium iterate the list even though the page doesn't exist anymore. I used 'driver.back()' and apparently it doesn't work.

The error message pops up after this line in the code:

```
link.click()
```

the linklist is located in this URL (I want to clink on the button Document and then download the first file after the refreshed page is displayed) 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001467373&type=10-K&dateb=20101231&owner=exclude&count=40'

Can someone have a look at this problem?
Thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
import html2text



class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
 def setUp(self):


    self.driver=webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html")


 def test_Login(self):
    driver=self.driver

    cikID="cik"
    searchButtonID="cik_find"
    typeID="//*[@id='type']"
    priorID="prior_to"
    cik="00001467373"
    Type="10-K"
    prior="20101231"
    search2button="//*[@id='contentDiv']/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/input[1]"


    documentsbuttonid="documentsbutton"
    formbuttonxpath='//a[text()="d10k.htm"]'


    cikElement=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(cikID))

    cikElement.clear()
    cikElement.send_keys(cik)


    searchButtonElement=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(searchButtonID))
    searchButtonElement.click()

    typeElement=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_xpath(typeID))
    typeElement.clear()
    typeElement.send_keys(Type)
    priorElement=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(priorID))
    priorElement.clear()
    priorElement.send_keys(prior)
    search2Element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_xpath(search2button))
    search2Element.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
    time.sleep(1)

    documentsButtonElement=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(documentsbuttonid))
    a=driver.current_url



    window_be1 = driver.window_handles[0]
    linklist=driver.find_elements_by_id(documentsbuttonid)


    with open("D:/doc2/"+"a"+".txt", mode="w",errors="ignore") as newfile:


        for link in linklist:

                link.click()            

                formElement=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_xpath(formbuttonxpath))
                formElement.click()
                time.sleep(1)

                t=driver.current_url

                r = requests.get(t)
                data = r.text

                newfile.write(html2text.html2text(data))

                drive.back()
                drive.back()


 def terdown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
if __name__=='__main__':
 unittest.main()
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but you're using `drive.back()` in the `for` loop instead of `driver.back()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a list of web-elements, but a list of links. Try something like this:

```
linklist = []
for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h4[@class="title"]/a'):
    linklist.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

And then you can iterate through list of links

```
for link in linklist:
    driver.get(link)
    # do some actions on page
```

If you want to physically click on each link, you might need to use

```
for link in linklist:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h4[@class="title"]/a[@href=%s]' % link).click()
    # do some actions on page
```

Comment: maybe you would like to have a look at this post @Andersson...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748555/python-threading-timer-set-time-limit-when-program-runs-out-of-time?noredirect=1#comment68724872_40748555