# python threading.timer set time limit when program runs out of time

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, timeout

I have some questions related to setting the maximum running time of a function in Python. In fact, I would like to use `pdfminer` to convert the `.pdf` files to `.txt`.

The problem is that very often, some files are not possible to decode and take extremely long time. So I want to set `threading.Timer()` to limit the conversion time for each file to 5 seconds. In addition, I run under windows so I cannot use the `signal` module for this.

I succeeded in running the conversion code with `pdfminer.convert_pdf_to_txt()` (in my code it is "`c`"), but I am not sure that the in the following code, `threading.Timer()` works. (I don't think it properly constrains the time for each processing)

In summary, I want to:

1. Convert the pdf to txt
2. Time limit for each conversion is 5 sec, if it runs out of time, throw an exception and save an empty file
3. Save all the txt files under the same folder
4. If there are any exceptions/errors, still save the file but with empty content.

Here is the current code:

```
import converter as c
import os
import timeit
import time
import threading
import thread

yourpath = 'D:/hh/'

def iftimesout():
    print("no")

    with open("D:/f/"+g+"&"+t+"&"+name+".txt", mode="w") as newfile:
        newfile.write("")


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        try:
           timer = threading.Timer(5.0,iftimesout)
           timer.start()
           t=os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, name)))[1]
           a=str(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, name)))[0])
           g=str(a.split("\\")[1])

           with open("D:/f/"+g+"&"+t+"&"+name+".txt", mode="w") as newfile:
                newfile.write(c.convert_pdf_to_txt(os.path.join(root, name)))
                print("yes")

           timer.cancel()

         except KeyboardInterrupt:
               raise

         except:
             for name in files:
                 t=os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, name)))[1]
                 a=str(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, name)))[0])

                 g=str(a.split("\\")[1])
                 with open("D:/f/"+g+"&"+t+"&"+name+".txt", mode="w") as newfile:
                     newfile.write("")
```

Comment: Will think on it one more time :)

Comment: @linusg that's so nice! Thx :))

Comment: This should do it, finally :)

Comment: @SXC88, I have no experience with `pdfminer`, but I've checked that it contains no `convert_pdf_to_txt()` method neither `converter.convert_pdf_to_txt()`... Do you mean `pdfminer.PDFConverter`?

Comment: Hi I just posted the converter.convert_pdf_to_txt() function below if you want to have a look, but I can actually convert all those files without problem but once I try to add time constraints to it, the code doesn't work properly... @Andersson

Comment: @SXC88 - I finally got it. See my totally updated answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following code and let me know in case of any issues. Also let me know whether you still want to use force termination feature (`KeyboardInterruption`)

```
path_to_pdf = "C:\\Path\\To\\Main\\PDFs" # No "\\" at the end of path!
path_to_text = "C:\\Path\\To\\Save\\Text\\" # There is "\\" at the end of path!
TIMEOUT = 5  # seconds
TIME_TO_CHECK = 1  # seconds


# Save PDF content into text file or save empty file in case of conversion timeout
def convert(path_to, my_pdf):
    my_txt = text_file_name(my_pdf)
    with open(my_txt, "w") as my_text_file:
         try:
              my_text_file.write(convert_pdf_to_txt(path_to + '\\' + my_pdf))
         except:
              print "Error. %s file wasn't converted" % my_pdf


# Convert file_name.pdf from PDF folder to file_name.text in Text folder
def text_file_name(pdf_file):
    return path_to_text + (pdf_file.split('.')[0]+ ".txt")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # for each pdf file in PDF folder
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_pdf, topdown=False):
        for my_file in files:
            count = 0
            p = Process(target=convert, args=(root, my_file,))
            p.start()
            # some delay to be sure that text file created
            while not os.path.isfile(text_file_name(my_file)):
                time.sleep(0.001)
            while True:
                # if not run out of $TIMEOUT and file still empty: wait for $TIME_TO_CHECK,
                # else: close file and start new iteration
                if count < TIMEOUT and os.stat(text_file_name(my_file)).st_size == 0:
                    count += TIME_TO_CHECK
                    time.sleep(TIME_TO_CHECK)
                else:
                    p.terminate()
                    break
```

Comment: Hi I have a new post if you want to have a look ;)) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828450/python-copy-folder-structure-under-another-directory @Andersson

Answer (score 5):

**I finally figured it out!**

First of all, define a function to call another function with a limited timeout:

```
import multiprocessing

def call_timeout(timeout, func, args=(), kwargs={}):
    if type(timeout) not in [int, float] or timeout <= 0.0:
        print("Invalid timeout!")

    elif not callable(func):
        print("{} is not callable!".format(type(func)))

    else:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        p.start()
        p.join(timeout)

        if p.is_alive():
            p.terminate()
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

What does the function do?

- Check timeout and function to be valid
- Start the given function in a new process, which has some advantages over threads
- Block the program for x seconds (`p.join()`) and allow the function to be executed in this time
- After the timeout expires, check if the function is still running

  - Yes: Terminate it and return `False`
  - No: Fine, no timeout! Return `True`

We can test it with `time.sleep()`:

```
import time

finished = call_timeout(2, time.sleep, args=(1, ))
if finished:
    print("No timeout")
else:
    print("Timeout")
```

We run a function which needs one second to finish, timeout is set to two seconds:

```
No timeout
```

If we run `time.sleep(10)` and set the timeout to two seconds:

```
finished = call_timeout(2, time.sleep, args=(10, ))
```

Result:

```
Timeout
```

Notice the program stops after two seconds without finishing the called function.

**Your final code will look like this:**

```
import converter as c
import os
import timeit
import time
import multiprocessing

yourpath = 'D:/hh/'

def call_timeout(timeout, func, args=(), kwargs={}):
    if type(timeout) not in [int, float] or timeout <= 0.0:
        print("Invalid timeout!")

    elif not callable(func):
        print("{} is not callable!".format(type(func)))

    else:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        p.start()
        p.join(timeout)

        if p.is_alive():
            p.terminate()
            return False
        else:
            return True

def convert(root, name, g, t):
    with open("D:/f/"+g+"&"+t+"&"+name+".txt", mode="w") as newfile:
        newfile.write(c.convert_pdf_to_txt(os.path.join(root, name)))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        try:
           t=os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, name)))[1]
           a=str(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, name)))[0])
           g=str(a.split("\\")[1])
           finished = call_timeout(5, convert, args=(root, name, g, t))

           if finished:
               print("yes")
           else:
               print("no")

               with open("D:/f/"+g+"&"+t+"&"+name+".txt", mode="w") as newfile:
                   newfile.write("")

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
             raise

       except:
           for name in files:
                t=os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, name)))[1]
                a=str(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, name)))[0])

               g=str(a.split("\\")[1])
               with open("D:/f/"+g+"&"+t+"&"+name+".txt", mode="w") as newfile:
                   newfile.write("")
```

The code should be easy to understand, if not, feel free to ask.

**I really hope this helps (*as it took some time for us to get it right ;)*)!**